# How to get a QHBoxLayout fixed height?

Tags: c++, qt

Here's my constructor:

```
DiskUsage::DiskUsage() {
    pathLineEdit = new QLineEdit;
    generateButton = new QPushButton(tr("Generate"));

    pathGroupBoxLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    pathGroupBoxLayout->addWidget(pathLineEdit);
    pathGroupBoxLayout->addWidget(generateButton);

    pathGroupBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Path"));
    pathGroupBox->setLayout(pathGroupBoxLayout);

    chartGroupBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Chart"));

    mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(pathGroupBox);
    mainLayout->addWidget(chartGroupBox);

    setLayout(mainLayout);
}
```

How can I get the pathGroupBoxLayout (which is a QHBoxLayout) a fixed height? I want that when the window is vertically resized, only the chartGroupBox resizes, but not the pathGroupBoxLayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just set verticalPolicy of your groupBox to fixed.

you can use

```
pathGroupBox->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred,QSizePolicy::Fixed);
```

for more options and information checkout [this link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qsizepolicy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you correctly. You seem to get a little bit wrong. The pathGroupBoxLayout is a layout inside your pathGroupBox. I does not govern the size of your pathGroupBox. You can't and certainly don't want to 'fix' the size of your pathGroupBoxLayout.

If you want to have your pathGroupBox not resizing, you give it (not the layout) a fixed size. pathGroupBox->setFixedHeight().

Comment: Good idea, but I have to provide an argument to this method... I would like to automatically size itself and then never resize anymore. So I should provide the current size to setFixedHeight but when I use pathGroupBox->height() the group box becomes huge.